# UIImagePickerController didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo delegate calling is delayed?

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.3

I am new to iphone development.I am implementing the UIImagePickerController in my application .When didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo delegate is called that is when choose button is clicked its having some delay .My code is as follows

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker   didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info 
{
       LGViewHUD* hud = [LGViewHUD defaultHUD];
       hud.activityIndicatorOn=YES;
       hud.bottomText=@"Login..";
       [hud showInView:picker.view];
       [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(pickerFunction:) withObject:info];
}

- (void) pickerFunction :(NSDictionary *)info
{
    profilePicture.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"];
    [imgPicker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

I am trying to bring a hud on choose button action but it comes only after some delay.Can any one suggest me a methods for this implementation.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: To which iPhone development are you new? **This** or that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything to do about it.

I've had the problem myself, and it seems that the lag is coming from UIImagePickerController calling the delegate method "didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo". Once it gets to that method, everything runs quickly. It doesn't matter what code you put into "didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo". The lag time happens BEFORE that method is even called.

I even tried this, which does nothing except dismiss the controller.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
     [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

and it still took a few seconds do dismiss the UIImagePickerController.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar delay occurring with this delegate. Turns out the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` isn't called until the image/video is compressed, which can take a few seconds depending on what it is.